# I Have problem for using pip install flask-mysqldb on window 10 64bit , I got an Error

Tags: python, mysql

I trying to install MYSQL on window 10 64 bit , I have python3.7.4 version when I tray pip install mysql I got Error  MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory , so I have 
Python Version: 3.7.4
Operating System: Windows 10
Pip Version: 20.1

Cannot pip install flask-mysqldb

Here is a summary of the error i'm getting...

---

```
C:\Users\Omar Faaruuq>pip install mysql
Collecting mysql
  Downloading mysql-0.0.2.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql, mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysql (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for mysql: filename=mysql-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl size=1252 sha256=fd9a7bdc9cfebc286a66598c32d555b935dfa38a3e1b687096dfa22bf50100d1
  Stored in directory: c:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\f6\60\6d\b1cf0653d003ddb0be2985a4d5f2c6f977d91f0862df094de8
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\OMARFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0eys0mm\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\OMARFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0eys0mm\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\OMARFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-usgog472'
       cwd: C:\Users\OMARFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m0eys0mm\mysqlclient\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "-Ic:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
  _mysql.c
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Successfully built mysql
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, mysql
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\OMARFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0eys0mm\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\OMARFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0eys0mm\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\OMARFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cc7qd2yb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\OMARFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m0eys0mm\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "-Ic:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\OMARFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0eys0mm\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\OMARFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0eys0mm\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\OMARFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cc7qd2yb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\omar faaruuq\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to install [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and [MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/c-api/)

or

Install mysqlclient through unoficiall wheel by [downloading](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) it and installing

```
 pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```